# Using MGSplitViewController inside UITabBar

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitabbar

Is anyone using [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) inside a `UITabBar`?

My objective is basically to use `UISplitViewController` inside a `UITabBar`. `UISplitViewController` doesn't work well inside a `UITabBar`. Specifically, `UISplitViewController` splits apart when device orientation changes.

Since `UISplitViewController` didn't work for me, i turned to `MGSplitViewController`. And now it seems that it's not a workable solution to be used with `UITabBar` either. Im running into all sorts of problems. Mainly the following:

I have a tab-bar with 3-4 tabs. Each one contains a `MGSplitViewController`. In general, the `MGSplitViewController` contains a Master (`UINavigationController`) and a Detail (`UIViewController`). When i rotate the device, the content (`UITableViewCell`) inside the `UITableView` is misaligned/disturbed. Scrolling the `UITableView` to show new cells fixes the misalignment. The Master has a Navigation bar and a search bar, and orientation change doesn't affect them. Any solution?

`MGSplitViewController` is great! But it's not being maintained.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Trying to go that same route myself right now, and hitting some walls!

Comment: I ended up using IntelligentSplitViewController (https://github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController). Worked for me!

Comment: Thanks! Looks like IntelligentSplitViewController doesn't have SplitView in portrait mode though..

Comment: It supports both orientation, and works inside a tab-bar like a charm.

Comment: It really does look great. But in portrait mode, I want to display a split view. This looks like it only has split view in landscape mode - right?

Comment: Uh, okay. For that, use APSplitViewController (https://github.com/SlavaBushtruk/APSplitViewController). I haven't tested it with UITabBar though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using IntelligentSplitViewController (github.com/grgcombs/IntelligentSplitViewController). Worked for me!